# Unity execute method when resolving type

Tags: c#, unity-container

Using Unity I'd like to execute a method to return an instance that should be injected into the constructor each time the type is resolved.

i.e. in the example below InitializeTest() is only executed once, and that is when the injectionContructor is defined. Ideally it should be executed twice, once each time ITestClass is resolved.

```
public interface ITestClass
{
    public string GetMyNumber();
}

public class TestClass : ITestClass
{
    private int _myNumber;
    public TestClass(int myNumber)
    {
        _myNumber = myNumber;
    }

    public string GetMyNumber()
    {
        return String.Format("My number is: {0}", _myNumber);
    }
}

public class Controller
{
    UnityContainer _container;
    public Controller()
    {
        InitializeContainer();
    }

    public void InitializeContainer()
    {
        if(_container == null)
            _container = new UnityContainer();

        container.RegisterType<ITestClass>(new TransientLifetimeManager(), new InjectionConstructor(InitializeTest()));
    }

    public int InitializeTest()
    {
        return new Random().Next(100);
    }

    public void ExecuteController()
    {
        ITestClass class1 = _container.Resolve<ITestClass>();
        ITestClass class2 = _container.Resolve<ITestClass>();

        // both statements below print the same number
        Console.WriteLine(class1.GetMyNumber());
        Console.WriteLine(class2.GetMyNumber());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, so lots of google later and a totally unrelated train of thought I found what I was looking for. Solution included for clarity:

```
container.RegisterType<ITestClass>(new TransientLifetimeManager(),
    new InjectionFactory(
        c =>
        {
            return InitializeTest();
        }
    )
);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use a ParameterOverride when resolving your instance from the container.

```
ITestClass class1 = container.Resolve<ITestClass>(
    new ParameterOverride("myNumber", InitializeTest());

ITestClass class2 = container.Resolve<ITestClass>(
    new ParameterOverride("myNumber", InitializeTest());
```

You should also create only once instance of the Random class and reuse it. Otherwise you will get the same numbers too.

```
private Random _random = new Random();

public int InitializeTest()
{
    return _random.Next(100);
}
```

Comment: However this means that every time I resolve ITestClass I have to execute extra code. is there no way to prepare the parameter as an IFunc and execute that code at the time of registration? Assuming TestClass constructor cannot change